# "Leaving a field intact for a season"

Tags: single-word-requests

In Czech, we have a special word for "leaving a field (agricultural) without seeding, resting." I wonder if English has such a word.

Comment: In the European Union bureaucracy, the modern word is *[set-aside](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/set-aside)*, part of paying farmers not to grow things.

Comment: @Henry I didn't know you did that in Europe too. Though to be fair, letting fields lie fallow is a legitimate and necessary practice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We do have it.  The word is *fallow*.

You'll frequently see it used in the following phrase:

> We let the field lie fallow.

Another possibility is *uncultivated* though that's probably less common.

Comment: I think there's a clear implication that a *fallow* field is [passively, temporarily] incorporated into an ongoing agricultural process, whereas an *unculivated* field might never have been farmed, and might not even be suitable in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I mostly agree, with the small tweak I would suggest that *fallow* could also indicate a field that was previously farmed but is no longer part of an "ongoing agricultural process".  E.g. *The fields of my ancestors have lain fallow for generations*.

Comment: maybe that's how *some* (you, aty least) see it, but personally I think it's oxymoronic for a field to lie fallow for generations. I was taught at school that you rotate different types of crop over 3 years, then lie fallow for one year. To "fix" the nitrogen, or something, I disremember.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm not sure what to tell you.  Certainly its usage in crop rotation is common, but if you like I can provide several links to usage examples where fields were left fallow for many years.  But I suppose that will only increase the *some* who believe like I do.

Comment: we all collectively define our shared language, and in a case like this I'm not going to argue that I'm right and you're wrong. But I would just say that I don't think you could use the word about land never cultivated. Only previously- (or imminently intended to be) cultivated fields can be left fallow, with the implication that they will soon be put back to use.

Answer (score 5):

In English, we speak of fields lying *fallow*.

From [TheFreeOnlineDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fallow):

> **fallow** Plowed but left unseeded during a growing season

Answer (score 3):

The NOAD reports that *fallow* is an adjective meaning "(of farmland) plowed and harrowed but left unsown for a period in order to restore its fertility as part of a crop rotation or to avoid surplus production."

Other words with a similar meaning could be *unplowed* (*unploughed* in British English), *untilled*, *resting*, *unsown*, or *bare*.

Comment: The difference between fallow and the other words you give is that only fallow connotes intent while the others connote neglect, except for resting. By the way, I think you meant to write "fallow" not "follow."

Answer (score 3):

My farming in-laws, in the American mid-west, use the term "set aside ground" to refer to fields that are not planted, or planted with a nutrient restoring crop that is not harvested for profit.