# What to call a field that the farmer let nature reclaim for becoming more fertile?

Tags: single-word-requests

I think every once in a while, farmers stop growing on some of their crops fields. They let all the natural and wild grasses, weeds, flowers, plants, etc. grow up in it. I think the purpose is to give the soil a "rest" so that the next time they grow crops on it, it has a better balance of nutrients.

What is the name of this process or this type of field?

Comment: One overlooked [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/17402/240807) in the duplicate is for [set-aside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-aside) which is also a term used in UK.

Comment: *Set aside* is generally used in the context of grants for non-use in the UK, rather than resting as fallow.

Comment: There is also "rewilding", but that is more long term...

Answer (score 7):

### fallow

> ##### adjective:
>
> 1. (of farmland) ploughed and harrowed but left for a period without being sown in order to restore its fertility or to avoid surplus production: *incentives for farmers to let land **lie fallow**.*
>
> ##### noun
>
> a piece of fallow land: a great estate was usually divided between fallows, grazed stubble, and wheat
>
> ##### verb
>
> leave (land) fallow for a period: *fallow the ground for a week or so after digging.*

Oxford Dictionary of English